# Could someone help me create a roman inspire warrior for a pathfinder game?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I was wanting to make a roman warrior for the newest game I'll be playing in. The DM likes the idea, but I wanted to get some advice before I started doing it. I was thinking about using the [gladiator class](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/tripod-machine/gladiator) to do it.

I plan to wear some kind of medium armor, a tower shield, and use a shortsword of some time and focus my abilities into dexterity.

I'm not sure what kind of armor is most similar to roman armor, though. I want something close to the Lorica segmentata, but I've no clue what would match it best, exotic or otherwise.

Does anyone have any advice on how to best create this character? It's a city based campaign, and the DM likes roleplaying, but he gets a bit hack and slashy when we're adventuring.

Additionally, I don't know a huge amount about how roman warriors fight. I like the look of the centurion, and wanted to match that style. I would assume that, since a gladius is more of a short sword, I should focus myself on dexterity more than strength.

I suppose what I'm asking is: with the gladiator class I linked, what feats and equipment would be good to take with the kind of character I'm looking to make? I'm researching Roman infantry now, but I was hoping more experienced people could advise me in the meantime.

I'm new to pathfinder, and they have buckets upon buckets of feats. I'm using the Gladiator class linked above, and I plan to have a tower shield, short sword, javelins, and medium armor, likely scale mail. In order to make this character as much as like a Roman Legionary, I would like advice on what feats and skills I should be taking to be as much like one as possible. I chose Gladiator because I felt it made a bit more sense, but if people are of the opinion that I should just take a straight fighter, I will go with that instead.

Comment: Banded mail is the closest equivalent to the lorica segmentata. You could use scale mail (lorica squamata) or a chain shirt (lorica hamata) for variety, remembering that hamata was the "low-brow" Roman armor, while the squamata and segmentata (or laminata, depending on where you dig for your records) are more high-end.

Comment: Can you add more requirements about what you'd like such a character to play like so that answers aren't just shots in the dark?

Comment: Are you only really asking about armour (I don't see anything else to answer here)?  If you're asking about more, it would help to ask plainly.

Comment: Hey @Sytakan. This is definitely a proper question, just that the answer is: "Whatever you like that fits the sort of fighting style you're going for. Also, put on some mail armor and describe yourself as looking like a gladiator and your armor being gladiator armor." There's not much for us to actually say or answer here, really! You can get hack 'n slashy in combat with basically any choices, provided you're holding something sharp. That makes it not a proper question for the site, but that's not bad since there's nothing you really need from us! Pick fun stuff.

Comment: (Also don't forget the armored kilt :D)

Comment: Are you interested in being a Roman era Gladiator, or a Roman era Centurion?  It looks like you want to do both, and they are very different fighters.

Comment: Centurions, in particular, make awkward *Pathfinder* characters, because their fighting style relied so much on their formation. While quite capable in single combat, surely, that’s not what they were trained for and it’s not what their standard (iconic) gear and tactics was designed for, but it’s very rare for *Pathfinder* characters to engage in a lot of large battles as parts of set formations.

Comment: Nit:  A centurion was the *leader* of a Century (a division of about 80 men).  I think the fighter people are referring to, is a "legionary".